# How can I prove that $T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^6$ is sufficient for $\theta$?

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

I’m revising for an exam in Mathematical Statistics and I have found the following problem in one of the previous exams (I don’t know the source):

> Let $X_1,…,X_n$ be a random sample that follows the Weibull distribution with parameters $\delta=\theta^{-1/6}$, $\eta=6$, where $\theta$ is unknown. Prove that $T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^6$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

Now, according to my book and notes on Neyman’s factorization criterion, I need to prove that $f(x;\theta)=G(t,\theta)H(x)$. So I went ahead and calculated:

$$f(x;\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\eta}{\delta}\cdot\bigg(\frac{x_i}{\delta}\bigg)^{(\eta-1)}\cdot e^{-(x_i/\delta)^\eta}$$

which, if I’m correct is:

$$f(x;\theta)=6\cdot \theta\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^5 \cdot e^{-\theta x_i^6}$$

and this is where I get stuck. I can make some changes and produce:

$$f(x;\theta)=6\cdot\theta\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\theta x_i^6} \cdot e^{\ln x_i^5} = 6\cdot \theta \cdot e^{-\theta \sum_1^n x_i^6}\cdot e^{\sum_1^n \ln x_i^5}$$

So, I have the $\sum_1^n x_i^6$ but I’m still left with the last part that I don’t understand. Can someone explain to me what I’m doing wrong??

Comment: If you are aiming for $f(x;\theta)=G(t,\theta)H(x)$ then you are almost there.  For example you can  take $H(x)= e^{\sum_1^n \ln x_i^5}= \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^5$ and $G(t,\theta)=6\theta  e^{-\theta t}$

Comment: Yes, thank you! I reread my result and an example in my book and realised right before I saw your comment, which verified it for me~